# Animated Banner Message Display Issue

Tags: html, css

I would like to add an animated message banner to a website. It works as expected on desktop and tablet view, however, when I go to a certain width in mobile view (roughly 570px), It doesn't display the full message. It takes away the last word of the sentence. The display message should say "Your reality is a matter of your perception". The word perception is being removed.

```css
.animated-message-container {
  height: 60px; 
  background-color:#339a9a;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
 }/*Makes changes to position of the text within the purple bar underneath the contact form*/

.animated-message-text {
  height: 50px;  
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
 }
 .animated-message-text h3 {
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.17%;
  /* Starting position */
  -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);  
  transform:translateX(100%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */  
  -moz-animation: example1 20s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: example1 20s linear infinite;
  animation: example1 20s linear infinite;
 }

 /* Move it (define the animation) */
 @-moz-keyframes example1 {
  0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes example1 {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
 }
 @keyframes example1 {
  0%   { 
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
  transform: translateX(100%);     
  }
  100% { 
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
  transform: translateX(-100%); 
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="animated-message-container">
  <div class="animated-message-text">
    <h3>"Your reality is a matter of your perception"</h3>
  </div>
<!--<p>Get in touch to discuss session availability.</p>-->
</div>
```

Does anyone know a way to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `h3` text is getting wrapped.

Add css

```
white-space : nowrap;
```

to prevent this. In this example, I've added it to the h3's css.

```css
.animated-message-container {
  height: 60px; 
  background-color:#339a9a;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
 }/*Makes changes to position of the text within the purple bar underneath the contact form*/

.animated-message-text {
  height: 50px;  
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
 }
 .animated-message-text h3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.17%;
  /* Starting position */
  -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);  
  transform:translateX(100%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */  
  -moz-animation: example1 20s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: example1 20s linear infinite;
  animation: example1 20s linear infinite;
 }

 /* Move it (define the animation) */
 @-moz-keyframes example1 {
  0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes example1 {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
 }
 @keyframes example1 {
  0%   { 
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
  transform: translateX(100%);     
  }
  100% { 
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
  transform: translateX(-100%); 
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="animated-message-container">
  <div class="animated-message-text">
    <h3>"Your reality is a matter of your perception"</h3>
  </div>
<!--<p>Get in touch to discuss session availability.</p>-->
</div>
```